# why am I getting the scrollbar when I have set the height to 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css

i don't know what silly mistake am i doing. But you see i have set the height to 100% for left side bar but i get a scrollbar what am i doing wrong

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/52zSJ/

```
html, body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
#wrapper2 {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom:-81px;
max-width: 1260px;
}
.admin-container {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
background:#CCC;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
.admin-content {
padding:10px;
}
.admin-nav {
background-color:#252b39;
min-height:81px;
}
.admin-logo {
float: left;
margin: 20px;
}
.admin-left {
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
background-color:red;
}
.row-height {
height: 100%;
background-color: #AAD;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: 100% is total area. But you have 1 div first (admin-nav) with 81px. In css3 you should use calc() function, but this don't work in all browsers. Like this #element { height: calc(100% - 81px); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you need to set the top property to zero. It is now 'floating' beneath the other element although it's positioned absolute.

http://jsfiddle.net/52zSJ/2/

```
.admin-left {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% is total area. But you have 1 div first (admin-nav) with 81px.

In css3 you should use calc() function, but this don't work in old browsers.

Like this:

```
#element { height: calc(100% - 81px); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need to use absolute positioning. The absolute positioning did take the total height of the page, where you want the total height of the parent element. Use a static position for this:

Where both columns should be 50%:

```
.columns
{
    width: 50%;
}
```

and you content wrapper should have the remaining total height which is not defined.

You can easily do this by giving your header a height, for example:

```
header
{
    height: 20%;
    background-color: #252b39;
}
```

Now you know your content should have a height of 80%:

```
.main-contents
{
    height: 80%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52zSJ/6/)**